# How many data types are there in Assembly language?

Tags: assembly, types

In c/c++ there're too many native data types.

What about assembly languages?

Comment: Assembly language doesn't have its own concept of "data type". You just push bits around.

Comment: What do you mean by 'too many'?  Which data types do you think aren't useful?

Comment: @BoltClock It depends on the assembly language. If we're talking about x86 in fasm's syntax, you don't push bits around, you actually push around words, double words, quad words.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In most assembly languages, there are no data types at all.  It's entirely the programmer's responsibility to make sure that all of the code agrees on what's what.  There are still usually various directives that you can use to get specific bytes/words/etc into memory, but there's definitely no type checking of any kind.

Comment: There is unsigned vs signed on the multiply and divide and signed vs unsigned overflow flags for add and subtract (V and C).  And for some architectures floating point.  In general though, yes, absolutely bits is bits and thats it.

Comment: @dwelch, that's all true, but without any checking, you can take signed or unsigned or floating point numbers and use them however you want to...

Comment: absolutely.  bits is bits.  you may choose to check other bits (flags, etc) in a data type specific way, but the operations dont care

Answer (score 2):

In x86 assembly, there are 8, 16, 32 (and 64 bit) integer as well as floating point registers.  There are also index and stack registers for accessing memory.  Anything more complex than that and you use a pointer to the structure and offsets to access the elements.